# flex: loading mxml component

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to load an mxml component into my main flex project.
I saw that there are many related question regarding this issue but i'm too of a newbie to understand them.

the page contains a vbox on left and right sides and another flash file in the middle.
i want the vbox's that are placed on the left and right sides to be in separated mxml component. how can i do so?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the mxml component for your side boxes.  In the following, I based it on `VBox` since that might be what you're looking for.  I gave it an obnoxious backgroundColor that should be easy to spot when we run the app.

SideBox.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100" height="300"
    backgroundColor="0x990000">
</mx:VBox>
```

So in your main mxml application you can include your custom component by telling the application what namespace to look for it (that's what the `xmlns:local="*"` is for - the word `local` is just a name so that I can easily remember what it means, you can call it anything, the `*` essentially means to look in the current/same directory).

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  
    xmlns:local="*" layout="absolute">

    <local:SideBox x="40" y="20" />
    <local:SideBox x="500" y="20" />
</mx:Application>
```